# How customizable is the checkout page?

Tags: bigcommerce

Hi I am wondering how customizable the checkout page is on the BigCommerce platform.

In my use case I would like to replace the product image on the checkout page to an `<iframe>`
Is that possible to do?

For example see in the image below, which is a standard render of the `checkout.html` file, I would like to edit 3 lines of code in the `{{{ checkout.checkout_content }}}` tag (see line 31 in the image below), but is it accessible? And are there any workarounds, like for example injecting javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking to do is customize your checkout. If so, you can modify the one page optimized checkout or create a custom checkout using our Checkout SDK.

Here are some helpful links;

[Open Checkout](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/customizing-checkout/open-checkout-quick-start)

[Checkout SDK](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/customizing-checkout/checkout-sdk)

[Checkout SDK Tutorial](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/customizing-checkout/checkout-sdk-quickstart)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Heather, I will have a look at it.